# Issue on excel vba script

Tags: vba, excel

I made the following script and I have a problem, the two first replace are working but not the replace in the if.
I tried a lot of different ways but it's still not working
Do you know why ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim totalCases As Integer
totalCases = Range("Q1").End(xlDown).Row

    For caseNb = 2 To totalCases Step 1
       replace_me_that caseNb, 17
    Next caseNb

    For caseNb = 2 To totalCases Step 1
       replace_me_that caseNb, 18
    Next caseNb

End Sub

Private Sub replace_me_that(ByVal caseNb As Integer, ByVal column As Integer)

Dim val As String
Dim objRegExp As Object
If (Cells(caseNb, column).Value = "") Then
    Exit Sub
End If
         val = Cells(caseNb, column).Value
         Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
           With objRegExp
               .Global = True
                .IgnoreCase = True
           End With
         objRegExp.Pattern = "\s*\(0\)\s*|\s*[()]\s*"
         val = objRegExp.Replace(val, "")
         val = Replace(val, ".", "")                       =>work
         val = Replace(val, " ", "")                       =>work
         If (Left(val, 2) = "33") Then                     =>condition true
             val = Replace(val, "33", "+33", 1)            =>don't work
         End If
         Cells(caseNb, column).Value = val

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, each cell was formatted as integer instead of text. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that either the 33 contained in the cell is seen as an integer or it is possible that you need to set the last option to "vbcomparetext". I usually use that option whenver I am comparing strings and it works well for me usually. Good Luck.

Comment: Just to add that if this is the case you could also wrap the val in a str:
 If (Left(str(val), 2) = "33")

Comment: @Mark Moore I can't do str(val) cause val is already a string.

Comment: @Thomas Beck Sutton How ? cause the LEFT function take two arguments (string, number of characters wanted), there is no other argument I think. Maybe you have another solution than the LEFT function ?

Comment: I tried to correct the following lines , the msgbox is displayed but it still not working, the display begin by "33" instead of "+33", Do you have any idea ?                                  If (Left(val, 2) = "33") Then                                            
               val = "+" & val
               MsgBox val
             End If